# Jest Mocking Nested Singleton Dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I am fairly new to Jest and am struggling to understand correct way of testing code that uses nested dependencies like MongoDb.

Here is my file hierarchy

`src/getOrder/index.js` <- code I want to test

`src/singletons/index.js` <- a singleton that will be created and used by `getOrder/index.js`

My `getOrder/index.js` looks something like this

```
const { getSuper, catchError } = require('../singletons');

module.exports = async function (context, req)
{
    let response = {}

    if (req.body.guid)
    {
        try
        {
            response = await getOrder(context, req);
        }
        catch (err)
        {
            response = catchError(context, err)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        response.data = 'Missing Payload'
        response.status = 400;
    }

    context.res =
    {
        status: response.status,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: response
    }
}

async function getOrder(context, req)
{
    //get API singleton 
    let sd = await getSuper()

    //get order
    let res = await sd.get(`/orders/${req.body.guid}`);

    //return
    return { 'status': res.status, 'data': res.data };
}
```

And then my `singletons/index.js` looks like this

```
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const DateTime = require('luxon').DateTime

const dbOptions =
{
    useUnifiedTopology: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true
};

//singleton variables

//mongo db connection
let db;

//super connection
let sd = {};

async function getDb()
{
    //establish db connection if one isn't present
    if (!db)
    {
        const client = new MongoClient(process.env.dbUri, dbOptions);
        db = await (await client.connect()).db(process.env.dbName)
    }
    return db;
}

async function getSuper()
{
    if (sd.exp && sd.exp > DateTime.local().toString().substr(0, 19))
    {
        return sd.instance;
    }
    else
    {
        //get db connection
        let db = await getDb()

        //get token
        let token = await db.collection('secrets').findOne({ 'name': process.env.SDAccessToken })

        //set exp time
        sd.exp = token.exp;

        if (!sd.instance)
        {
            //creat axios instance
            sd.instance = axios.create({
                baseURL: process.env.SDApiUrl,
                httpsAgent: new https.Agent({ keepAlive: true }),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })

            //set token
            sd.instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token.value}`
        }
        else
        {
            //update token
            sd.instance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token.value}`
        }

        return sd.instance;
    }
}

function catchError(context, err)
{
    let response = {}

    if (err.response && err.response.data)
    {
        response.status = err.response.status
        response.data = err.response.data
        context.log(response)
    }
    else
    {
        context.log(err)
        response.status = 500
        response.data = err
    }

    return response;
}

module.exports =
{
    getDb,
    getSuper,
    catchError
}
```

Notice how when the `sd` singleton is initialized it also uses the `db` singleton (it calls `getDb`)
So I am unsure how to mock either of these from my test file. I AM trying to use `@shelf/jest-mongodb` to mock my database, however I am quite unsure how to turn into a singleton under a mock `getDb` function that will live somewhere outside of the test (so it can be reused in other tests, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Essentially I figured out that as long as you have the mocking package I was using (@shelf/jest-mongodb) configured in the `jest.config.js` file and the `jest-mongodb-config.js` file then it will mock the db functionality where it is initialized. Whether it's directly in your tests, or 5 nest submodules deep in your project folder